# Add TypeConverter attribute to enum in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, attributes, typeconverter

In a C#/WPF application I added a TypeConverter attribute to some of my enums in order to display a localized text instead of the text of the enum:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(LocalizedEnumTypeConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    EnumVal1 = 0,
    EnumVal2 = 1,
    EnumVal3 = 2,
}
```

I have implemented LocalizedEnumTypeConverter to perform this task.

The problem arises when I try to use the same approach with an enum that is defined in another assembly, that has no access to LocalizedEnumTypeConverter, and it is shared with other applications (that is, I cannot add a reference to the assembly where LocalizedEnumTypeConverter is defined).

Is there a way to add the TypeConverter attribute in runtime? This way I can leave the enum in the other assembly without the TypeConverter attribute, and then add it in runtime in my application.

Comment: Since they are in different assemblies and dont share a common code base, why not implement LocalizedEnumTypeConverter in the other assembly as well?

Comment: The point is that LocalizedEnumTypeConverter is part of an assembly intended for localization, that I don't want to add as a reference to the other projects that access the enum, if I can avoid it. Besides, my approach avoids modifying the shared enum, as the attribute will only be added in my current program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done using TypeDescriptor class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx. Refer the below sample.

```
    Attribute[] newAttributes = new Attribute[1];
    newAttributes[0] = new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(LocalizedEnumTypeConverter));

    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(MyEnum), newAttributes);
```