# Adding TypeConverterAttribute at runtime does not result in correct TypeConverter

Tags: c#, attributes, typeconverter, typedescriptor

For serialization/deserialization purposes I'd like set a TypeConverter for a type located in an external, compiled assembly.

I stumbled over this question but the provided solution does not seem to be working for me:
[Add TypeConverter attribute to enum in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673882/add-typeconverter-attribute-to-enum-in-runtime)

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(ExternalType),
new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExternalTypeTypeConverter)));
```

Calling

```
TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(typeof(ExternalType));
```

returns the attribute as expected, but calling

```
TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(ExternalType));
```

does not return the previously added converter but just the TypeConverter base class.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting it turns out that the solution was already correct but was not working due to my run configuration. When using the "normal" entry point everything works fine (I was using the static debug hook of the latest ReSharper release, see http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/28/run-configurations-debug-any-static-method-in-visual-studio-and-more/)